# Replace string with another depending on another line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I need to write a script, that goes through a bunch of text files and replaces a certain string with another. The other one is located two lines below the certain string. Like this:

```
some text
this is the first line (helloWorld).
this is the second line.
This is the third line (patternxxx).
more text
```

And I want this:

```
some text
this is the first line (helloxxxWorld).
this is the second line.
This is the third line (patternxxx).
more text
```

I'm under Linux.

Comment: spenibus, thx for editing

Comment: What did you try so far? Is doing this with `sed` or within a shell requirement?

Comment: Any solution is acceptable :) I just tagged sed 'cause I thought that's going to be a solution.

Comment: @prologic quick note, use `@` in front of a username to notify the user, details in [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { mr=3 }
  /helloWorld/{ mr=0; gsub("helloWorld","helloxxxWorld");print; };
  mr==2 { gsub("pattern", "patternxxx");}
  mr++
'
```

test:

```
$ cat file
some text
this is the first line (helloWorld).
this is the second line.
This is the third line (pattern).
more text
some text
this is the first line (helloWorld).
this is the second line.
this is the second line.
This is the third line (pattern).
more text

$ awk '
  BEGIN { mr=3 }
  /helloWorld/{ mr=0; gsub("helloWorld","helloxxxWorld");print; };
  mr==2 { gsub("pattern", "patternxxx");}
  mr++
' file
some text
this is the first line (helloxxxWorld).
this is the second line.
This is the third line (patternxxx).
more text
some text
this is the first line (helloxxxWorld).
this is the second line.
this is the second line.
This is the third line (pattern).
more text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using sed, see below command. this will permanently make changes in the files.

```
sed -i 's/helloWorld/helloxxxWorld/g' file1 file2 ...filen
```

You can loop files one by one also.

```
 for file in `ls`;
 do
 sed -i 's/helloWorld/helloxxxWorld/g' $file;
 echo "$file completed";
 done
```

make sure you have backups for the files.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '1N;N;s/(hello)(World.*\n.*\n.*pattern(xxx))/\1\3\2/;P;D' file1 file2 ...
```

Open a three line window in the file and pattern match on the first and third lines throughout the file.